# A question about Dedekind-infinite sets and Peano natural integers.

Tags: logic, axiom-of-choice, axioms, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

I've doubt about Dedekind-infinite sets, sets which are in bijection with a proper part, in the ZF axiomatic framework, without Axiom of Choice.

Assume a Dedekind-infinite set X exists.

Then it can be proved X contains a Dedekind-infinite N set which satisfy the Peano Axioms.

This set N can be well ordered using traditional arguments from Peano Axioms.

It can also be proved its initial chains, in this well order, I_n = { m < n }, are Dedekind-finite.

Can be proved they are also finite using the ZF definition of "finite set", without any further assumption?

Comment: You may find useful my blog posting on defining finite or infinite sets at https://www.dcproof.com/Infinity.html  There, I start by developing a non-numeric definition of a finite set based on a walk through a finite village. This in contrast to the usual approach using Hilbert's Infinite Hotel to develop the notion of an infinite set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The definition of finite is being equipotent with a proper initial segment of $\omega$, that is the ordinal corresponding to $\Bbb N$.

Once you have established a bijection, and in fact an order isomorphism, between your "copy of $\Bbb N$" and $\omega$, and you have by virtue of it being a model of $\sf PA_2$, then the initial segments correspond exactly to the actual finite cardinals.

The axiom of choice is needed when you want to prove that a Dedekind-finite set is finite. This is not what you're doing here. You're not arguing that these are Dedekind-finite, you're quite literally defining them to be finite.

Comment: Hence, taking your words, assuming a Dedekind-infinite set exists is enough to build a model of PA2 and allow the existence of a countable well ordered set, a well order isomorphic with the one of the first infinite ordinal, omega.

But once we built the first infinite ordinal, each countable set, a set in bijection with a model of natural integers N, can be well ordered, using the bijection to induce a well order on the set.

Does this mean assuming one Dedekind-infinite set exists imply the Countable Axiom of Choice, in the ZF axiomatic framework?

Comment: No, ZF proves the existence of infinite ordinals, all of which, almost trivially, are Dedekind infinite. Again, choice is only necessary when you try to prove the equivalence between infinite and Dedekind infinite.

Comment: I asked a different question.

Assuming at least one Dedekind-infinite set exists, in the ZF axiomatic framework, imply Countable Axiom of Choice?

Not the general Axiom of Choice, just the countable instance of the axiom.

Comment: And I answered. No. ZF proves there are Dedekind infinite sets, but it does not prove countable choice.

Comment: Right. Then something has to be wrong in the logic of my main question.

If you read what I wrote, adding what you wrote, we may prove just this statement:

"The existence of at least one Dedekind-infinite set exist IMPLY Countable Axiom of Choice".

Which is FALSE.

Something has to be wrong in my assumptions above.

Isn't it?

Comment: I don't see why we may prove that implication. You didn't prove it, you wished it. Wishful thinking does not make a proof.

Comment: Yes I understand I didn't prove it. It is FALSE, of course I didn't.

What I wish is understanding where is the flaw.

May you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You didn't offer an argument, so I can't point to a failure. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717961/countable-axiom-of-choice-why-you-cant-prove-it-from-just-zf/ might be a starting point, as are the questions linked on the right, and those linked there, etc.

Comment: "Assume a Dedekind-infinite set X exists.

Then it can be proved X contains a Dedekind-infinite N set which satisfy the Peano Axioms.

This set N can be well ordered using traditional arguments from Peano Axioms.

It can also be proved its initial chains, in this well order, I_n = { m < n }, are Dedekind-finite."

Let me to ask my question in a different way.

Any of the statements above is FALSE in the ZF framework?

Comment: No, the definition of Dedekind infinite lets you avoid the need for using choice. Not to mention, as I keep repeating, ZF already proves the existence of Dedekind infinite sets (so no need to confuse yourself with "assume one exists"). Finally, note that the statement "every infinite set is Dedekind infinite" is weaker than countable choice. So you're overreaching twice.

Comment: Yes, the assumption "at least one Dedekind-infinite set exists" is redundant, in the ZF framework. I keep repeating it for habit, apologies.

But then I don't understand why I didn't offer an argument.

If a model of PA2 exists, a set N which is isomorphic to Peano Integers, and it seems I can prove it from your words, why I can't prove each set in bijection with N is well ordered?

Comment: Yes, but why is that a problem? Well ordered sets exist even without the axiom of choice. You need choice when you want all sets to be well ordered.

Comment: Ops. Does this mean "each countable set can be well orderded" is not equivalent to "Countable Axiom of Choice"? Is this my mistake?

Comment: Yes, that is your mistake apparently. A countable set, by definition, can be well ordered.

Comment: Answer accepted. Thank you so much for your time and patience.

Comment: You're very welcome.